# Is there any way to display a MKMapView correctly inside UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to develop an UITableView with UITableViewCells. Inside them I have various information and a UIStackView which will contain the MKMapView.

I have a function inside the class of UITableViewCell:

```
func applyMapView(vehicle : VehicleHolder){
        let cordoonates = vehicle.vh_coordinates

    if (vehicle.vh_coordinates == "," || vehicle.vh_coordinates == ""){
       

    }else{
        let arrayCordoonates = cordoonates.split(separator: ",")

        let latitude = String(arrayCordoonates[0])
        
        let longitude = String(arrayCordoonates[1])
        
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        
        mapStackView.addArrangedSubview(mapView)
        
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        mapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180.0).isActive = true
        
       mapViewDirections = MapViewDirections(mapView: mapView, currentVehicleLatitude: latitude, currentVehicleLongitude: longitude)
    }
}
```

Which gets called when I call the setVehicle function:

```
func setVehicle(vehicle : Vehicle, indexPath: IndexPath){
        applyMapView(vehicle: vehicle)
}
```

and the setVehicle is called right here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let vehicle = vehicleList[indexPath.row]
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "vehicle") as! VehicleCell
        
        cell.setVehicle(vehicle: vehicle, indexPath: indexPath)
        cell.delegate = self
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.clipsToBounds = true
        
        return cell
}
```

The problem is that when I run this code, I have a UITableViewCell with 3 MKMapViews inside them or I have MKMapView on cell which I don't need them (see the if statement inside applyMapView) and when I scroll I can have even more.

I do know that the cells are reusable but I don't know how to handle this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, cells are reusable so a cell may already have a map view installed when it is recycled from the queue.

Your code unconditionally adds a map view on each call to `setVehicle`. You can use `UITableViewCell.prepareForReuse` to reset the state in a way that works for you.

You can keep a reference to the map view and then conditionally add or just reset the coordinates.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    var mapview: MKMapView?

    //strip the mapview , probably not very efficient
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        mapview?.removeFromSuperview()
        mapview = nil
    }

    func applyMapView(vehicle : VehicleHolder) {
        installMapView()
        setupMapview(vehicle)
    }

}
```

or alternatively:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    var mapview: MKMapView?

    //hide the mapview , might have layout effects you need to deal with
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        mapview?.isHidden = true
    }

    func applyMapView(vehicle : VehicleHolder) {
        if mapview == nil {
            installMapView()
        }

        setupMapviewAndUnhide(vehicle)
    }
}
```